# Sun JMS bridge to ActiveMQ to .NET

Tags: activemq-classic

I have Sun's Message Queue 4.3. Default installation on localhost using imqbroker daemon. Opened one queue.

I want to consume messages written to the queue above from .NET.

I understood there is ActiveMQ solution, version 5.3.
Checked ActiveMQ for .NET (version 1.1) and it works OK for ActiveMQ queues which are similar to Sun JMS.

My problem is that I want to bridge my existing Sun MQ 4.3 to an ActiveMQ queue and the documentation in http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html
is not very clear.

can someone point exactly how to map activemq's config file to bridge:
Sun MQ queue named QUEUE1 on imqbroker@localhost:7676 (maybe jms port 1545? default install)

to

ActiveMQ queue named QUEUE2 on activemq:tcp://localhost:61616

I'm loosing it .... Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Camel [JMS component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) to connect the different brokers:

AFAIK Camel is included in ActiveMQ.